# setMethodCallHandler never run on BeaconsPlugin for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, beacon, altbeacon

I want scan beacon devices, I'm using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/beacons_plugin . I wrote the code like plugin's example code but i only see 2 print in my console. I can't see 3. print and can't startMonitoring.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      //Prominent disclosure
      print('HELLO ANDROID');
      await BeaconsPlugin.setDisclosureDialogMessage(
              title: "Title",
              message:
                  "Message")
          .then((value) {
        print('HELLO ANDROID 2');
      });
      // await BeaconsPlugin.clearDisclosureDialogShowFlag(false);
      BeaconsPlugin.channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
        print("Method: ${call.method}");
        if (call.method == 'scannerReady') {
          await BeaconsPlugin.startMonitoring();
        } else if (call.method == 'isPermissionDialogShown') {
          print("Prominent disclosure message is shown to the user!");
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many way to solve this bugs, but in the end I've surrender and find another way. So i just combine with native code (kotlin & swift) to get beacon data and then catch it with

> platform.invokeMethod

in flutter. It Works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).